# Compatibility Of Android Application

Tags: android, android-compatibility

Please anyone tell me that how to make android application compatible on all devices?
I want to run the same application on tablet, which is running well on 320 * 420.
I tried following things:-

1. Made all images suitable to ldpi,mdpi,hdpi and xhdpi and wrote the code for corresponding layout as layout-small, layout-normal, layout-large, layout-xlarge respectively.
2. Following in manifest file:-

But still it's not working properly.
Please suggest something helpful. . 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to code accordingly. you need to set your xml in such a way that it can support the devices / size you want. No shortcut here

Comment: Explain which part is not working properly. Does it fail to run on other devices, or does look wrong?

Comment: I think the issue is that google Play does not show his application on some devices. @vinay is that correct ?

Comment: @ anthropomo : it looks wrong. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a problem with Layout or we can say UI. You did not explain what is your actual problem,But If you have problem with UI that is If images you use is not showing properly on all device then you have to use different Images with High,medium and low resolution and put it as in hdpi,mdpi,ldpi folders,other things you done right using `support screen` and all. You can use 9 patch tool for this. Use high definition Images so It will good for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should not place same size images in every folder (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi), For ldpi design different layout and images , for mdpi design different layout and images and so on for others too . If you will follow this pattern it will work.
For details information check this link

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: It means I have to write separate xml for each screensize.

Comment: exactly , Thats the best practice

Comment: Hey it's no working. I wrote the separate layout for each xml according the corresponding density but still it's running according to layout-normal.I mean Xhdpi have to take layout-xlarge but it's taking layout-normal xml.What should I have to do?